# GXT menu aligning improperly

Tags: java, javascript, gwt, alignment, gxt

I have a strange aligning problem with my GXT Menu (com.extjs.gxt.ui.client.widget.menu). It does horizontally align properly to MenuBarItem (also com.extjs.gxt.ui.client.widget.menu) only when the scorllbar is visible. You can see both cases visualized on the images below (Chrome 33):

[image: no scrollbar]
[image: with scrollbar]

The aligning is invoked in the expand event of my custom class MenuBarImpl extending MenuBar

```
public class MenuBarImpl extends MenuBar implements IMenuBarImpl {
  (...)
  @Override
  protected void expand(MenuBarItem menuBarItem, boolean selectFirst) {
    MenuBarItemImpl item = (MenuBarItemImpl) menuBarItem;
    (...)
    item.getMenu().show(item.getElement(), "tl-bl?", new int[] {1, 0});
    (...)
  }
  (...)
}
```

While debugging I found that the problem seems to be JavaScript function getAbsoluteLeft()(com.google.gwt.dom.client.DomImpl). To my surprise it returns the same left coordinate for both scenarios: when there is a scrollbar visible and when there isn't. Looking at it's short body (see below), it builds the value on 2 DOM properies offsetLeft and offsetParent. And so I checked values of these properies for both cases using Chrome Developer Tools. The values were alright - they should produce different results for both invokes of getAbsoluteLeft() function.

```
public native int getAbsoluteLeft(Element elem) {
  var left = 0;
  var curr = elem;
  // This intentionally excludes body which has a null offsetParent.    
  while (curr.offsetParent) {
    left -= curr.scrollLeft;
    curr = curr.parentNode;
  }
  while (elem) {
    left += elem.offsetLeft;
    elem = elem.offsetParent;
  }
  return left;
}
```

I'm confused especially that the result is right, when the scrollbar is visible and not when it isn't. Anybody knows any way to fix it?

Comment: This does not look like the default GXT style? Have you created your own style?

Comment: I fixed it myself, though it took me more than 8 hours. First after  show() I called once more (it's invoked by show()) alignTo() method. It positioned menu almost correctly, but had problems when margin on some elements were set to auto and it calculated to value with ending decimal .5. GWT stores everything as integers and it probably cut the ending .5, while browsers seem to be rounding it up. The result was menu was shifted by 1px then. To correct that I re-wrote getAbsoluteLeft() method to Java and call it explicitly in my class. Now it works alright.

Comment: As for the style, yeah, I created my own style.